# Http Post for HTMLImageElement

Tags: javascript, html, angular, post

I want to make a post request. The body of the request should have a `FormData`. I have a `HtmlImageElement`. How do I approach from here? I find no direct solutions to this. The code is something like this. I cannot put the `image` in the `FormData`.

```
image: HtmlImageElement = getImage();
const form = new FormData();
this.http.post<any>(this.url, form);
```

Comment: you want to send/upload image?

Comment: Yes. I want to upload it. POST it

Comment: Its src contains a long string. Will sending that work?

Comment: can you post that string and whats in getImage method?

Comment: Let's just say getimage just returns document.createElement('img');

Comment: This seems so simple. There must be something I am missing here

Comment: what does src have?

Comment: Image src  data:image/png;base64,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

Comment: and it goes on like that

Comment: Yes sending it will work as its a base64 value.